# Decoding an analogue signal with a given sample and signal frequency that aren't in sync

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I am trying to decode an analogue signal, that is intended to be converted to a digital one and decoded as USART communication. [image]In the image shown the blue trace is the analogue signal, and the filtered (using a moving-average filter) signal is shown in red. The signal shown is sampled at 1 MHz, but has a USART baud rate of 115200bps (thus, one bit is received every 8.68 us, shown by the vertical green traces).

I am trying to successfully decode this message by considering the no. of bits per sample and an appropriate threshold voltage, of which to assign zeroes or ones. If I consider every 8th or 9th bit, I end up introducing errors into the digital signal. How does one process a signal when the sampling and message frequency aren't in sync?

Comment: Wouldn't this be more suitable to ask on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

For UART you have to wait for the start bit. To know, when sampling must be started. At the end of each message, when the stop bit is received you have to wait for the next start bit. This keeps you synchronized.